# Permissions on PHP executable - Giving more than just web server permission

Tags: linux, php, apache-2.4

I was prompted with the idea of opening up the permissions on the PHP executable to more than just the webserver. PHP executable meaning `/usr/bin/php` or `/usr/bin/php-cli` or where ever it is on your system.

I'm not sure if that is cause for concern in terms of security. My initial reaction was that it would allow these additional profiles the ability to write their own PHP scripts and run them without restriction. But then I realized, whatever those script do they would still be bound by their permissions. So I'm starting to think there isn't much harm in it.

Is giving additional profiles access to call on the PHP executable relatively common? Or is it suggested against?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can certainly change the permissions on PHP, but remember that the PHP script a user runs under their own account cannot do anything that user also cannot do. So it's not really a security problem. Indeed, all distributions which ship PHP have it executable by everyone.

Comment: Thank you, I slowly came to that realization after my knee-jerk reaction, just wanted to make sure, just to be safe.